# Angular 4 update model with JSON

Tags: json, angular

Can I update JSON vars in my Model without have all the params?

Example:

JSON

```
{ param1: "field1", param3: "field3" }
```

Model:

```
var param1; var param2; var param3;
```

And only update param1 and param3 and keep param2 initial value?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking... can't you just do `model.param1 = "whatever"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Object.assign():

```
const model = {param1: value1, param2: value2, param3: value3};
const newPartialData = {param1: newValue1, param3: newValue3};

//Updata model
model = Object.assign(model, newPartialData);
```

Comment: Working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the spread operator

```
let model : YourModel = {
    param1: ‘value’,
    param2: ‘value’,
    param3: ‘value’
};

const partialModel: Partial<YourModel> = {
    param1: ‘value’,
    param3: ‘value’
};

model = {
    ...model,
    ...partialModel
};
```